# Unreachable Code #2

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having a hard time identifying the issue with the following method I've written. It will not currently compile due to error "Not all code paths return a value":

```
private static int compareVersionNumbers(string installedVersion, string requiredVersion)
    {
        if (installedVersion.Equals(requiredVersion))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Versions are identical.");
            return 0;
        }
        else if (installedVersion != (requiredVersion))
        {
            // Split version strings into arrays.
            List<string> versionArray = installedVersion.Split('.').ToList<string>();
            List<string> otherVersionArray = requiredVersion.Split('.').ToList<string>();

            int count = 0;

            while ((count < versionArray.Count()) && (count < otherVersionArray.Count()))
            {

                // Fetch current version component
                int currentPart = Convert.ToInt32(versionArray.ElementAt(count));
                int otherPart = Convert.ToInt32(otherVersionArray.ElementAt(count));

                if (currentPart > otherPart)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(installedVersion + " is greater than " + requiredVersion);
                    return 1;
                    break;
                }
                else if (currentPart < otherPart)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(installedVersion + " is less than " + requiredVersion);
                    return -1;
                    break;
                }
                count++;

            }

        }
    }
```

In general, are there any helpful tools in VisualStudio's debugger for troubleshooting unreachable code?

Comment: For me VS grays out unreachable code. Probably a Resharper feature.

Comment: From the error message, your problem isn't with unreachable code at all. It's with reachable code paths which do not return a value.

Comment: @QuestionEditor: What's the point of adding "#2" in question title? Moreover! question is related to some basic programming.  There is always an "else" case. Don't understand how a programmer can write a code without understanding this simple logic.

Answer (score 4):

You have one `if` and one `else if` statement. But you don't have an `else` statement which means if your all conditions are false then your function won't return value.Change your `elseif` statement to `else` statement if it's just the opposite of your `if` statement (which seems like that), or return a value end of your function.

Comment: The conditions can never all be false. The second condition is the inverse of the first. But the compiler doesn't know that. Besides, as the other answers show, this is only part of the problem.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't recognize that. I thought C# compilers were a bit smarter.

Comment: @LeventeKurusa The optimizer might recognize stuff like that. The compiler specification which decides which code is valid should have a simple specification.

Comment: @LeventeKurusa For unreachable code analysis, the C# spec intentionally requires compilers to not be smart. There are multiple compilers, and higher priority was given to making the behaviour consistent.

Comment: The Op is using an else if.  If instead the code just used an else, the compiler would stop whining.

Comment: Indeed, but there might be an option when the `while` will not run and hence no return value.

Comment: @hvd I don't see how they're inverses. One is `<` and one `>`. So you can fall through if both inputs are equal when interpreted as version but not as string. e.g. `01` vs `1`.

Comment: `!=` is not always the inverse of `.Equals`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I thought this answer was referring to the outer `if`: `if (installedVersion.Equals(requiredVersion)) { ... }  else if (installedVersion != (requiredVersion)) { ... }`

Comment: @JohnSaunders Not in general, but do you have any counterexample for strings?

Comment: I changed the else if statement to simply "else" per suggestion:

`else /*(installedVersion != (requiredVersion))*/`

But the compiler still shows error "not all code paths return a value"

Answer (score 2):

The problem you get means that the compiler has found at least one way where your function will not return a value. These particular cases are the following:

1. No return value after the `while` loop. It might be that the `while` will not even run.
2. After the `else if` block put an `else return -1;`

Answer (score 1):

Your function have 2 if clause and retrun instruction only inside if clause. You should have 1 else clause for the 2nd if clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the compiler analyzing your code in blocks.
And it find a block (the inner else if) that doesn't return the required integer

Also if all of the inner paths of the while returns something the compiler still complains because the else if block doesn't return anything

Let me show a contrived example based on your code above with some of the fixes proposed:

```
int Test()
{
    int a = 10;
    if(a < 10)
    {
        // Always false but the compiler is happy here 
        // because this block returns the integer
        return 1;
    }
    else if(a==10)
    {
        // We always enter here but the compiler doesn't check at this point 
        // if the condition is true or not neither what happen inside the while block
        // It looks at the else if and conclude that you don't return the integer 

        while(a < 20)
        {
            // Again, we know that we always enter the while block but 
            // the analysis is not executing our code and  
            // it is already been decided that something is wrong
            if(a < 15)
                return 2;
            else if(a < 18)
                return 3;
            else
                return 4;  // Adding this else doens't make any difference
            a++;
        }

        ??????? here the compiler wants something to return
    }
    else
    {
        // happy here because the block returns the integer
        // but, again,  adding this else doesn't make any difference
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Still the error isn't gone away, for the compiler, the inner if else doesn't return an integer while our logic tells us that this is impossible

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I simply needed another return after the if / if else if blocks:

```
private static int compareVersionNumbers(string installedVersion, string requiredVersion)
    {
        if (installedVersion.Equals(requiredVersion))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Versions are identical.");
            return 0;
        }
        else if (installedVersion != (requiredVersion))
        {
            // Split version strings into arrays.
            List<string> versionArray = installedVersion.Split('.').ToList<string>();
            List<string> otherVersionArray = requiredVersion.Split('.').ToList<string>();

            int count = 0;

            while ((count < versionArray.Count()) && (count < otherVersionArray.Count()))
            {

                // Fetch current version component
                int currentPart = Convert.ToInt32(versionArray.ElementAt(count));
                int otherPart = Convert.ToInt32(otherVersionArray.ElementAt(count));

                if (currentPart > otherPart)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(installedVersion + " is greater than " + requiredVersion);
                    return 1;
                    break;
                }
                else if (currentPart < otherPart)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(installedVersion + " is less than " + requiredVersion);
                    return -1;
                    break;
                }
                count++;

            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
```